# Mapbox minimum zoom extent

Tags: python, mapbox, vector-tiles, mapbox-gl

I uploaded a custom shapefile (converted to geoJSON) using the mapbox python [SDK](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-sdk-py) and visualize it in a Jupyter Notebook using the MapboxGL python [module](https://github.com/mapbox/mapboxgl-jupyter).

After I successfully upload the GeoJSON file as a tileset the minimum zoom level is set to 5 which makes visualizing this data at a global scale impossible. Mapbox point to this [doc](https://www.mapbox.com/help/adjust-tileset-zoom-extent/#why-this-happens) and suggests going the tippecanoe route. Is there another option that doesn't require to compile another package? Ideally I would like to overwrite these zoomlevel restrictions if necessary.

[Upload script](https://github.com/wri/Aqueduct30Docker/blob/master/notebooks/production/Y2018M07D03_RH_Upload_Hydrobasin_Mapbox_V01.ipynb)

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately you'll need to use tippecanoe to set your own min zoom.

Comment: In hindsight the experience with tippecanoe was pretty straight forward. The only challenge I found is that I am using a containerized environment (Docker on EC2) that failed to compile on the first try. Updating compiler and other dependencies solved the issue.